# Как в доп. окне заблокировать действия

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как в доп. окне заблокировать действия: растягивание(в любую сторону) запретить сворачивать, и разворачивать на весь экран, и установить стандартное разрешение окна на 345 x 154

Код:

```
import psutil
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Menu, simpledialog, messagebox
import subprocess


class TaskManagerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Task Manager")

        self.process_tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        self.process_tree["columns"] = ("PID")
        self.process_tree.column("#0", width=250)
        self.process_tree.column("PID", width=100)
        self.process_tree.heading("#0", text="Process Name")
        self.process_tree.heading("PID", text="PID")
        self.process_tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, width=40)
        self.search_entry.pack()

        self.process_tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.show_context_menu)

        update_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Update", command=self.update_running_processes)
        update_button.pack(pady=10)
        
        add_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add Process", command=self.add_process)
        add_button.pack()

        self.selected_pid = None
        self.process_groups = {}  # Словарь для группировки процессов по имени

    def clear_process_groups(self):
        for process_group in self.process_groups.values():
            self.process_tree.delete(process_group)
        self.process_groups = {}

    def update_running_processes(self):
        self.clear_process_groups()  # Очистка групп перед обновлением
        search_text = self.search_entry.get().lower()

        for pid, name in self.get_running_processes():
            if search_text in name.lower():
                process_group = self.process_groups.get(name, None)
                if process_group is None:
                    process_group = self.process_tree.insert("", "end", text=name, values=(pid))
                    self.process_groups[name] = process_group
                else:
                    self.process_tree.insert(process_group, "end", text=name, values=(pid))
                    
    def update_all(self):
        self.update_running_processes()

    def get_running_processes(self):
        processes = []
        for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
            processes.append((process.info['pid'], process.info['name']))
        return processes

    def select_process(self, event):
        item = self.process_tree.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        if item:
            self.selected_pid = int(self.process_tree.item(item, "values")[0])
        else:
            self.selected_pid = None
            
    def show_process_properties(self, process):
        try:
            properties = process.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'exe', 'username', 'create_time', 'memory_info'])
            properties_str = "\n".join([f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in properties.items()])
            messagebox.showinfo("Process Properties", properties_str)
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e)

    def open_file_location(self, file_path):
        try:
            subprocess.run(["explorer", "/select,", os.path.normpath(file_path)])
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e)

    def show_context_menu(self, event):
        self.select_process(event)
    
        menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Kill", command=self.kill_selected_process)
    
        if self.selected_pid is not None:
            try:
                process = psutil.Process(self.selected_pid)
                properties_available = True
            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                properties_available = False
        
            if properties_available:
                menu.add_command(label="Properties", command=lambda: self.show_process_properties(process))
            
                if process.exe():
                    menu.add_command(label="Open File Location", command=lambda: self.open_file_location(process.exe()))
                else:
                    menu.add_command(label="Open File Location", state=tk.DISABLED)
            else:
                menu.add_command(label="Properties", state=tk.DISABLED)
                menu.add_command(label="Open File Location", state=tk.DISABLED)
            
        menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

Часть кода с окном

```
    def add_process(self):
        process_name = simpledialog.askstring("Add Process", "Enter process name:")
        
        if process_name:
            try:
                process = psutil.Popen(process_name)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            self.update_all()
```

```
            
    
    def kill_selected_process(self):
        if self.selected_pid is not None:
            try:
                process = psutil.Process(self.selected_pid)
                process.terminate()
                process.wait()
                process.suspend()

            except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
                pass
            self.update_all()

            # Завершить explorer.exe и отключить его восстановление
            try:
                subprocess.run(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", "explorer.exe"])
                subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command", "Stop-Process -Name explorer -Force"])
                subprocess.run(["powershell", "-command", "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon' -Name AutoRestartShell -Value 0"])
            except Exception as e:
                print("An error occurred:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")  
    root.minsize(800, 600)    
    app = TaskManagerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы достичь заданных ограничений для дополнительного окна, вам нужно внести несколько изменений в код. Вот как это можно сделать:

Запрет на растягивание окна: Для этого можно использовать метод .resizable() и передать ему аргументы False, False, чтобы запретить растягивание окна по горизонтали и вертикали.

Запрет на сворачивание и разворачивание на весь экран: Для этого можно использовать метод .attributes() и установить атрибуты "-toolwindow" в значение "1", чтобы предотвратить сворачивание и разворачивание на весь экран.

Установка стандартного размера окна: Для этого можно использовать метод .geometry() и передать ему желаемые размеры.

Примените эти изменения к вашему коду:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Task Manager")
    root.geometry("345x154")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.attributes("-topmost", "1")
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", "1")
    root.attributes("-toolwindow", "1")  # Заблокировать кнопку сворачивания
    
    app = TaskManagerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```